# Is there any formula to compute $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac {1}{k^k}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

Is there any formula to compute $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac {1}{k^k}$? Where the value of $k$ ranges from $1$ to $n$.

Comment: There is no simple closed form for this sum. However you can write it as the integral $\int_0^1\frac{{\rm d}x}{x^x}$ if you want (when $k$ ranges from $1$ to $\infty$).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore's_dream